# merge two array php and replace values

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I have 2 array as below :

```
Array 1
(
  [0] => c1
  [1] => c2
  [2] => c3
)

Array 2
(
   [0] => Son
   [1] => Daughter
   [2] => Son
)
```

Output required :

```
Array (
  c1  => Son
  c2  => Daughter
  c3  => Son 
)
```

Can anyone please guide to generate this output ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$array_result = array();

foreach($array1 as $key => $val) {
    $array_result[$val]=$array2[$key];
}
```

So you are building a new array (array_result), while using the values from array1 as the keys and the values from array2 as the values of the new array.

As @max-p wrote, [array_combine()](http://php.net/array_combine) does the same thing as the above and it's one line, so go with that, but hopefully the example illustrates what's going on.

Comment: simply great ! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php

```
$a = array('c1', 'c2', 'c3');
$b = array('Son', 'Daughter', 'Son');
$c = array_combine($a, $b);

print_r($c);
```

Answer (score -2):

If the array elements will always be the same number you can try this foreach function:

```
$arr1 = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3'];
$arr2 = ['Son', 'Daughter', 'Son'];
$output = [];

foreach ($arr1 as $key => $element) {
    $output[$element] = $arr2[$key];
}
```

Or you can use the PHP defined function `array_combine()`:

```
$output = array_combine($arr1, $arr2);
```